# JavaScript document.getElementById() Not Working

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason, this exact web page is not working properly.
I am trying to make the text input update to the current iframe source, but I can't event write text to it.

I can't get "currenturl" to update, or change in value.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height"/>
    <meta name="content-type" content="UTF-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        input[type=text]#txt{
            z-index:inherit;
            position:absolute;
            top:0%;
            left:0%;
            width:99%;
            display:block;

        }

        iframe#frame{
            z-index:inherit;
            position:absolute;
            top:4%;
            left:0%;
            width:99.5%;
            height:96%;
            display:block;
        }

        input[type=button]#go{
            z-index:inherit;
            position:absolute;
            top:0%;
            right:0%;
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function isUrl(s) {
            var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
            return regexp.test(s);
        }

        function GoToPage(txt,event){
            try{
                if(event.keyCode==13 || event=="null"){
                if(isUrl(txt)){
                    frame.src=txt;
                }
                else{
                    window.open("https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q="+txt+"&pbx=1&oq="+txt+"&aq=f&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1172l1858l0l2027l4l4l0l0l0l0l192l557l0.4l4l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=eba7411258d36659&biw=1024&bih=681");
                }
                }
            }
            catch(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        }

        function GetURL(){
            try{
            alert(frame.src);
            }
            catch(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        }

        window.onload=function(){
            try{
                frame=document.getElementById("frame");
                currenturl=document.getElementById("currenturl");
                currenturl.value="test";
                if(!localStorage.settings){
                    localStorage.settings='{"homepage":"homepage.html"}';
                    SettingsObj=eval("(" +localStorage.settings+ ")");
                    alert(SettingsObj.homepage);
                }
                //localStorage.settings="";
                setInterval("GetURL()",100);
            }
            catch(err){
                alert(err);
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <input type="text" id="currenturl" value="" onkeyup="GoToPage(this.value,event);"/>
        <iframe src="../blank.html" id="frame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for which browser you are getting an error?

Comment: i checked your source and you are using jquery as well. any reason for not using $("id") ?

Comment: Can you describe what your end goal is with this code?  Right now, it's a timer polling for an iframe .src value which looks like some sort of hack.  What are you really trying to accomplish so we can direct you to a proper way to solve your problem?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, once I removed the interval (and the localStorage).  http://jsfiddle.net/D5jVF/

Comment: What he's trying to do is be able to type a URL into a textbox, hit enter, then it loads whatever he typed into the textbox. See my answer below for more.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval("GetURL()",100);
```

All this is doing is spamming you with alerts. I set the interval to a longer time and it stopped spamming me, and your textbox worked fine.

Comment: Oh, well that was just a test to see if the interval was working.

I forgot to mention that I was just testing it prior.

Answer (score 0):

try commenting this:

```
if(!localStorage.settings){
                    localStorage.settings='{"homepage":"homepage.html"}';
                    SettingsObj=eval("(" +localStorage.settings+ ")");
                    alert(SettingsObj.homepage);
                }
                //localStorage.settings="";
                setInterval("GetURL()",100);
```